# Stripe payment has happening two times

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am writing subscription code for stripe everythiing is working but payment is enter two times (two payment rows are inserting for same customer on payment section on stripe).

```
  $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
        "name" => $plan_name,
        "id" => $plan_name,
        "interval" => "month",
        "currency" => "usd",
        "amount" => $amount_cents,
    ));

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
             'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
             'email' => 'hp@ph1.com'
    ));


    $subscription= \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
          "customer" => $customer->id,
          "plan" => $plan->id,
    ));

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(    
        "amount" => $amount_cents,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "customer" => $customer->id,
       )        
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u subscribe your customer for plans so why u also charge it.

just remove below code

```
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(    
        "amount" => $amount_cents,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "customer" => $customer->id,
       )        
    );
```

Comment: there is no need to charge if we are using subscription?

Comment: because if a user is subscribed to plan then it will auto charge plan amount which they subscribe.

Comment: thanks, mahipal, How can we send billing information(city, state, etc) to the stripe?

Comment: for that you need to check stripe document.

Comment: if my answer helps you pl. approve it so other users get quick help.